# How can I get all available width?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have a linear layout with horizontal orientation.
The left side of the layout is a linear layout with a vertical orientation.
The right side of the layout is a small view of fixed width 80dp * 80dp.
**Problem:**
If I set the left layout with width "match_parent" the right layout is not visible.
If I set the right layout with "width=0dp" and "weight=1" to get as much space as available it just wraps around the content. I mean that it does not go all the way to the next element on the right.

How can I make sure that the left element expands **all** the way to the parent width minus the 80 dp occupied by the right element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the "match_parent" option will push out anything else that is with it in that layout. Try "fill_parent" on the left layout which leaves room for other things.

Comment: They're actually both the same thing, it was just renamed http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html#FILL_PARENT

Comment: @karaokyo:I see different behavior

Comment: @Jim Honestly, you must have changed something else. As you can see in the Android documentation they literally have the same value. If it really does make a difference, I would be interested in seeing your code.

Answer (score 2):

The general approach for this is to leave the right element's width hardcoded to your 80dp and set the following on the left:

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

This allows the right element to measure itself and reserve its 80dp and then the parent grants all the additional space to the left element since it's weight is 1.

Edit:

To explain a little further why match_parent pushes your right hand element offscreen -- LinearLayout will perform two layout passes when it has a child with a layout_weight. The first pass will allocate the minimum amount of space based on the specified widths/heights. It is during this pass that your match_parent element will behave as you're seeing and fill it's parent container, thus pushing the right element offscreen. Then, during the second layout pass, the parent LinearLayout will allocate any left-over space according to the layout_weight attributes. There is none left to allocate, so nothing changes.

If, however, you use a layout_width="0dp" on the left element, it will get no space during the first pass, and your right element will get the 80dp that it requested. During the second pass, the LinearLayout parent will allocate the remaining width according to the weights -- so in this case the left element will receive all of the unused space.

Comment: Yes this is what I am doing but it does not expand all the way. It does not actually use all the available space.

Comment: I'm reading that you tried the opposite -- setting the weight on the right element. I'm suggesting you set weight on the left element. Keeping in mind that the layout_width="0dp" does matter, since match_parent here will force the right element offscreen.

Comment: No. The OP says: `The right side of the layout is a small view of fixed width 80dp * 80dp`

Comment: This should work. Make sure the attribute is named *layout_weight* rather than *weight*. Also make sure you don't set any weight on the view on the right. Clarification: the linear layout with vertical orientation and the view should be both inside the linear layout with horizontal orientation.

Comment: Maybe it would clear up some of the confusion if you shared your layout file?

Comment: Actually, check out Michael Krause's answer, it's exactly what I was suggesting.

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try (background colors are for visualizing what is going on only):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#00ff00">

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="#ff0000"/>

</LinearLayout>
```